# How do I write png hex values stored in a string to a png file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hex, png

I have a png image hex values stored in a string but I want to write this to a new png file to be viewed. I currently using the Ruby code below (with a small png example) but the hex values are slightly off when I check the output in the new png file. Where am I going wrong?

```
png_hex = "89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000000d0000000d08030000004535144e0000000774494d4507d7041517171c5943ea76000000097048597300000b1100000b11017f645f910000000467414d410000b18f0bfc610500000015504c544500000086c1e01544706ba4da4a85c6386c9f427ab6583bfce90000000174524e530040e6d866000000434944415478da558d41120030040395c8ff9f5cd421dd0b6b02b3e198c24f1d22c72996bed1683c89ae3d2f4856ed6570795b317dec0da45aba04ad2e761cfb7a4228bb5cb30147915c409a0000000049454e44ae426082"

File.open("temp.png", "w"){|fh|
 fh.print png_hex.scan(/.{2}/).map{|u| u.to_i(16)}.pack("C*")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"wb"` instead of `"w"` to open the file in binary mode:

> ```
> "b"  Binary file mode
>      Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And
>      sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly
>      specified.
> ```

[(source)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/IO.html#method-c-new)

By the way, you can call 
[`IO#putc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/IO.html#method-i-putc) to directly write an 8-bit integer to the IO stream without having to create an array and packing integers:

```
File.open("temp.png", "wb"){|fh|
  png_hex.scan(/.{2}/) { |e| fh.putc(e.hex) }
}
```

Comment: Ahh I knew it would be something small that I missed. Thanks for the quick reply and the alternative solution!